# Records as map keys in clojurescript

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

```
(defrecord Pot [a])

(def p (Pot. 1))

(def m {p 2})

(m p) ; Returns 2 in both Clojure and Clojurescript

(m (Pot. 1)) ; Returns 2 in Clojure and nil/null in Clojurescript
```

In Clojure, looking up a value either with the original key, or a newly constructed key returns the desired value. However, in Clojurescript, with a newly constructed key it returns null/nil. What's the best way to make the lookup work in Clojurescript as it does in Clojure?

Comment: Just tried this at a ClojureScript REPL running the current master and it works as expected. Could you be using an outdated version?

Comment: Thanks. That works. I also had a problem with any record that I declared in my namespace not working properly. I tried cleaning my 'out' directory and eventually created a new project from scratch and this fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I have to implement equals myself for records in clojurescript:

```
(defrecord Pot [a])

(extend-type Pot
  IEquiv
  (-equiv [this that] (and (instance? Pot that) (= (into {} this) (into {} that)))))
```

Works fine with this. I would have thought Clojurescript would implement equals for records by default.